# Selecting a column from a metadata-table in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am starting with sqlalchemy and so far I have

```
import sqlalchemy

db = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql://CONNECTION?charset=utf8&use_unicode=0')
connection = db.connect()
db.echo = True
metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData(db)

details_file = sqlalchemy.Table('details_file', metadata, autoload=True)

query = details_file.select([details_file.c.Id]).\
        where(details_file.c.RunId == 5859)
res = query.execute()
```

What I am attempting is to just select the column `Id` that meets the where criterion.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you use the [select](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/expression_api.html?highlight=select#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select) construct directly:

```
from sqlalchemy import select

select([details_file.c.Id]).where(details_file.c.runid == 5)
```